# Pourquoi est-ce que le nom de la lettre « g » est prononcé « gé » (/ʒe/) et pas « gué » (/ɡe/) ?

Tags: prononciation, alphabet

Bien sûr, le ***g*** est prononcé /ʒ/ devant ***e, i*** et ***y*** (***g***éant, **g**igantesque). Mais il est prononcé /ɡ/ devant ***a, o, u, l*** et ***r*** (***g***are, **g**oût, **g**ustation, **g**uerre, **g**lace, **g**ras).

Alors, pourquoi est-ce que le nom de la lettre ***g*** est prononcé ***gé*** et pas ***gué*** ? Quelle est l’origine de la prononciation « gé » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On dirait bien /ge/ en latin, une prononciation qui est devenue /ʒe/ en français moderne, comme chaque réalisation de /g/ avant /e/ du latin. En d'autres termes, le mot a évolué comme si on l'écrivait

> ge

en latin. (La même chose est vraie pour la lettre « c » qui était bien /ke/ en latin, une prononciation que est devenue /se/ en français moderne, comme chaque réalisation de /k/ avant /e/ du latin.)

Comment: C’est très logique. Avez-vous des références que vous puissiez ajouter à votre réponse ?

Comment: malheureusement que non. Je l'ai trouvé dans cet article, qui n'est pas disponible en français https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet

Answer (score 2):

Le nom masculin et invariable de la lettre est `G` prononcé /ʒe/ .
Ce n'est qu'un problème de nom mais de prononciation.

Il y a aussi :

- a*gg*lomération,
- *g*eisha (emprunt à une langue étrangère),
- ja*gua*r (emprunt à une langue étrangère),
- *gh*etto (emprunt à une langue étrangère),
- an*gui*lle,
- *gn*ome,
- *gnô*le (franco-provençal),
- campi*ng* (emprunt à une langue étrangère),
- Ma*gd*eleine (le *g* ne se prononce pas),
- ga*geu*re *[(autre problème non résolu)](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/vous-dites-a3737989)....*

qui échappent aux règles que vous mentionnez.

Comment: C’est précisément le ‘problème’ de prononciation que m’intéresse. Pourquoi /ʒe/ et pas /ɡe/?

Comment: @Jacinto autrefois (et peut-être encore pour certains), on apprenait l'alphabet 'phonétiquement' : *a, beu, ceu, deu e feu geu* pour *A, B, C D E F G* parce que *beu + a --> ba*. http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/G dans le dernier § répondra peut-être à votre attente.